# 40400 Endpoint not found-error from Azure service bus (App function)

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

Im trying to create an "azure app function", that is listening on a Service Bus queue. Im using the quick start-method, so the only writing so far has been inserting the connection string

I have created a service bus instance and a queue and  a policy permission (listen). I copied that connection string and removed the last part of it, so I my connection string is connection

```
Endpoint=sb://bla.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=bla-policy-principal-queue-listen;SharedAccessKey=<thekey>
```

I get error message :

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus: 40400: Endpoint not found., Resource:sb://bla.servicebus.windows.net/mysbqueue0.
```

I have seen a couple of similar questions but not for app functions, and the answers didnt make any sense to me. There are no code except the logging that was in the template

Im sending the messages from dynamics 365. Do I have to register the listener somewhere?

All suggestions are welcome, troubleshooting, or anything :)

Comment: Did you try to connect to the same queue from a another program (like a console app for example) ? Is it working ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. It works fine in a stand alone .net 461 app but if I copy and paste that code to use in a function, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify queue name aswell